# get int value from XmlTextAttribute when deserialize xml to class in c#

Tags: c#, serialization

xml as below :

```
<Item>
   <Winner>2</Winner>
</Item>
```

For my class definition I have the following:

```
    public enum HomeOrAwayTeamType {Home =1,Away =2,Draw =3,NA = 0};

    class Item
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public virtual HomeOrAwayTeamType Winner { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Winner"), XmlText]
        public virtual string WinnerSerializer
        {
            get { return this.Winner.ToString(); }
            set
            {
                //get 'Away' from HomeOrAwayTeamType
                this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)2; //ok
                this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)Convert.ToInt32("2"); //ok
                this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)int.parse("2"); //ok 

                //get 'NA' from HomeOrAwayTeamType
                this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)Convert.ToInt32(value); //fail
                this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)int.parse(value); //fail
             }
         }    
    }

    string xml = ""; //xml code
    Item model = default(Item);

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
        model = (Item)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

hi, guys..
How get int value from XmlTextAttribute?

Please help~

Comment: See: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2013/12/deserializing-to-an-enum/

Comment: thanks a lot, yet not solved .

Answer (score 0):

Your xml string is empty. This works for me:

```
string xml = "<Item><Winner>2</Winner></Item>"; //xml code
```

`this.Winner` gets set to `Away`

Comment: thanks.. but yet not gets 'Away' value from enumType

Comment: What do you get? Do you get an exception? What do you mean when you say  fail over here `this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)int.parse(value); //fail`

Comment: for example ,  in xml , if TextNode value of "Winner" Element is 2 (<Winner>2</Winner>) then i hope to get   "Away" of enumType.
but, i get "NA" of enumType when execute this.Winner = (HomeOrAwayTeamType)int.parse(value);
how get correct value of  enumType Corresponding to xml value.

Comment: sorry. i'm english beginner. because not enoughmy express.

Comment: i solved this problem.
my mistake..haha
it is to remove 'TextXml'
thanks a lot.

Comment: remove XmlText in below source.

[XmlElement(ElementName = "Winner"), XmlText]
        public virtual string WinnerSerializer
        {.........